# Convert decimal hours to HH:MM:SS

Tags: r, time, format, decimal

I'm looking for a way to convert decimal hours to HH:MM:SS

For instance, as input:

```
4.927778 hours
```

Desired output:

```
04:55:40
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try something like below

```
dh <- 4.927778
strftime(as.POSIXct(dh * 60 * 60, origin = Sys.Date(), tz = "GMT"), format = "%H:%M:%S")
## [1] "04:55:40"
```

Comment: It is good to point out that this only works for values < 24 hours because otherwise you will end up on the next day, which resets the the %H value to 0.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to get an idea of what you need to do -

```
a <- "4.927778 hours"
a <- as.numeric(gsub(x = a,pattern = " hours", replacement = ""))

h <- a%/% 1
m <- ((a%% 1)*60) %/% 1
s <- round((((a%% 1)*60) %% 1)*60,0)
paste(h,m,s,sep = ":")
#[1] "4:55:40"
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative solution is to convert this to a date/time class and then format it in an appropriate way.

```
format(ISOdatetime(1900,1,1,0,0,0, tz="GMT") + 
       as.difftime(4.927778, unit="hours"), "%H:%M:%S")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sprintf()` to format the output as you wish when you have the number of hours, minutes and seconds as integers. These can be calculated using modulo (`%%`) and `floor()`/`round()`. The number of hours can be extracted from a string very nicely using the `parse_number()` function from the readr package:

```
library(readr) 
input <- "4.927778 hours"
hrs <- parse_number(input)
hours <- floor(hrs)
minutes <- floor((hrs %% 1) * 60)
seconds <- round((((hrs %% 1) * 60) %% 1) * 60)

sprintf("%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds)
```

The advantage of this strategy is that it still works for time differences larger than 24 hours in contrast to the solutions using `strftime()`.

Answer (score 0):

This should work with negative values as well.

`convertHours<-function(hours){
  timeoffset<-as.numeric(as.POSIXct(format(Sys.time(), tz = "GMT")) -  as.POSIXct(format(Sys.time(), tz = "")))
  hoursMinutes<-ifelse(hours<0,paste0("-",strftime(as.POSIXct((abs(hours)+timeoffset) * 60 * 60, origin = Sys.Date(), tz =""), format = "%H:%M")),                               strftime(as.POSIXct((hours+timeoffset) * 60 * 60, origin = Sys.Date(), tz =""), format = "%H:%M"))
}`

> h<-1.33
>
> hhmm<-convertHours(h)
>
> hhmm [1] "01:19"
>
> h<--1.33
>
> hhmm<-convertHours(h)
>
> hhmm [1] "-01:19"

Answer (score -1):

If you are using .net/C# you can use a little bit of date math.

```
var when = DateTime.UtcNow; // or any time of your choice
var later = when.AddHours(4.927778);
var span = later - when;
Console.WriteLine(span)
```

I see the R flag now.  Perhaps this will give you a hint where to look for something similar.  I don't know R.

Comment: The language is [R](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_(programming_language)) (and whenever I see example code I get a little bit confused).