# Convert time in hours from numeric to HMS format

Tags: r, datetime, time, format

How to convert numbers that represent time in hours from numeric to HMS format.

for example:

```
8.0 -> 08:00:00
0.5 -> 00:30:00
0.25 -> 00:15:00
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert decimal time to time format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46167536/how-to-convert-decimal-time-to-time-format)

Comment: Can you please specify the `class` of the desired output - is it `character` or a dedicated time class? If the latter, you have `data.table::as.ITime(x*3600)`.

Comment: ...or `chron::times(x/24)`.

Comment: [Convert decimal hours to HH:MM:SS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19721145/convert-decimal-hours-to-hhmmss)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert to seconds, make use of `seconds_to_periods` from `lubridate` and change it to `hms`

```
hms::hms(lubridate::seconds_to_period(floor(v1 * 60 *60)))
#08:00:00
#00:30:00
#00:15:00
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c(8, 0.5, 0.25)
```

Answer (score 5):

Another base R option :

```
x <- c(8, 0.5, 0.25)
format(as.POSIXct(x * 3600, origin = '1970-01-01', tz = 'UTC'), '%T')
#[1] "08:00:00" "00:30:00" "00:15:00"
```

Comment: Elegant solution.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a base R option

```
h <- x%/%1
m <- floor(x%%1 * 60)
s <- round((x%%1 * 60)%%1*60)
sprintf("%02d:%02d:%02d",h,m,s)
```

such that

```
> sprintf("%02d:%02d:%02d",h,m,s)
[1] "08:00:00" "00:30:00" "00:15:00" "03:45:22"
```

**Data**

```
x <- c(8.0,0.5,0.25,3.756)
```